# AngularJs and HTML5 required fields setting fields to empty fires validation

Tags: html, validation, angularjs

I'm trying to write a small Angular app with the following functionality:

Form starts empty with placeholder text. 
User enters item in required textbox.
Angular pushes item to collection.
Reset form inputs to default.

I've got code that looks like this (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn37v/1/) :
HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="talkForm">
        <input ng-model="newVoice" placeholder="Say something" required />
        <button ng-click="saySomething()">Say</button>
    </form>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in conversation">{{c}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.conversation =[];
    $scope.saySomething = function(){
        if ($scope.talkForm.$valid){
            //push to list
            $scope.conversation.push($scope.newVoice);
            $scope.newVoice='';
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when $scope.newVoice='' executes, the form is rendered invalid and I get the helpful HTML5 validation pop up to encourage me to fill in the form properly. Obviously this is not the behaviour I want - what is the correct way to do this with Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the following pull request in 1.1.x branch of Angular will add a $setPristine method to allow this to happen

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1127

Answer (score 2):

To remove the HTML5 validation (since it will only work on compliant browsers) why not add the `novalidate` attribute to the form?

The validity of the form will still be invalid due to the 'required' attributed.