# How to get a filtered angular string as a js function parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a string that goes through angular's filter as a parameter for a javascript function. Angular doesn't parse it, how do I fix this?

```
<input type="text" ng-required="true" ng-model="foobar"
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity({{ 'String' | myfilter }})">
```

The {{ .. }} does not go through Angular's parsing. If I remove the double quotation marks it still doesn't work as Angular 'fixes' it to be oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(**"**{{

Also, if there is another, more angular way of customizing the browser validation message, that would do the trick for me also.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `foobar` directly

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity({{ 'String' | myfilter(foobar) }})"
```

Comment: This is not what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the [angular documentation for input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input), in particular the example plunker provides the solution to your question.

If you still want a hint on what to do to use a filter in your argument please provide information about your `oninvalid` directive.

Comment: Oninvalid is not my directive, but a HTML5 parameter for input field. When leaving a field empty that is 'required' (ng-required renders to both ng-required as well as required) then the browser displays it's own error, typically "Please fill out this field." The oninvalid -parameter is what the browser runs when the field is not a valid one. The attribute setCustomValidity is the javascript one to set the error value instead of "Please fill out this field." I need to localise this string, that is what the filter does.

Comment: I see, didn't understood your problem cause i didnt knew the html5 attribute behaviour. I now think that writing your own directive is the way to go to stay in the angular realm. As this seems to be a pretty standard use case, maybe you are lucky and find an existing directive at github / bower / npm. Also the answer to this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550836/angularjs-and-html5-required-fields-setting-fields-to-empty-fires-validation suggests that HTML5 validation isnt fully supported and you might be better off just disabling it and rolling your own with angular.